# Can the Trinidad server use log files in development?

Tags: jruby, pry, trinidad-gem

I'm working on an app that's served using [Trinidad](https://github.com/trinidad/trinidad), and in development, the server defaults to pushing all of its output to `stdout`. This is making it very difficult to use a command line debugger (in my case Pry). Is there some way to make it use log files in dev the way that it does in prod? For reference, I'm using version `1.4.4` of Trinidad.

Alternatively, if there's some workaround for this in Pry, I'd love to learn about that too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was actually due to a logger monkey patch in my specific app, which was otherwise using log files. I was just thrown off by the Trinidad README on GitHub, which claims that printing to stdout is the default in dev.

If anyone has clever ideas for working around a situation like this using Pry and/or Unix utilities, please share anyway as that might be useful in other similar scenarios.